# what is xfsprogs doing in ubuntu install?

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, mate, xfs, ubuntu-mate

I was just watching Ubuntu installer do its thing, and it said "completely removed xfsprogs". I'm just wondering why it installed it? This is a clean install. is xfsprogs part of the installer (Mate 15.04)?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be there? People might want to use an XFS partition for root, or for any other partition they might create from the installer.

Comment: Yes if you need it you want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xfsprogs), it is needed for XFS filesystem. If you don't need it then remove it, but other applications might depend on it such as Gparted.

[image: 1]